useContext Nextjs giving error: " Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured"
its my middle component used in page.tsx. giving error here
"use client"

import React from 'react'
import { CiSearch } from 'react-icons/ci'
import { FaPlus } from 'react-icons/fa'
import Image from "next/image";
import { BsThreeDots } from 'react-icons/bs';
import friend4 from "../public/src/man 1.jpg"
import friend2 from "../public/src/girl 2.jpg"
import friend3 from "../public/src/man 2.jpg"
import friend1 from "../public/src/man 3.jpg"
import { HiPlus } from 'react-icons/hi';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Contexts, LocalSContext } from '../contexts/LocalSContext';







const Middle = () => {


    const { setTask, desc, myapp, setDesc, setType, handleAddTodo, handleRemoveTodo } = useContext(Contexts)

    // Blog Local----








    return (

        <div className=' w-[96%] flex flex-col '>
            <div className='flex flex-row justify-between align-bottom  h-20 '>
                <p className='text-gray-600 text-lg flex items-center justify-center pl-12 '> Active Sprint</p>
                <div className='bg-inherit  w-1/4 border-b border-slate-300 h-[50%] mt-5 align-bottom justify-center align-center flex '>
                    <input className=' bg-inherit text-xs outline-none w-[70%]' placeholder="Search task ,project ,label ..." />
                    <CiSearch className=' w-[25px] h-[25px] mt-2  text-gray-400' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className=' w-full min-h-screen bg-indigo-50 rounded-[40px] items-center flex flex-col  '>
                <div className='flex flex-row justify-between items-end h-[60px] w-[93%] '>
                    <div className=' flex flex-row gap-2 items-center'>

                        <Image
                            className=' w-[35px] h-[35px] rounded-full'
                            src={friend1}
                            alt='faceless'
                        />
                        <Image
                            className=' w-[35px] h-[35px] rounded-full'
                            src={friend3}
                            alt='faceless'
                        />
                        <Image
                            className=' w-[35px] h-[35px] rounded-full'
                            src={friend2}
                            alt='faceless'
                        />
                        <Image
                            className=' w-[35px] h-[35px] rounded-full'
                            src={friend4}
                            alt='faceless'
                        />

                        <button className=" w-[120px] shadow-lg text-sm font-semibold h-[30px] ml-3 shadow-gray-300 rounded-2xl bg-white text-black border-0 hover:bg-blue-200  hover:text-blue-600">
                            Invite People
                        </button>
                    </div>



                    <div className="">
                        <div className=" w-[142px] h-[42px] text-white border-0 flex rounded-full justify-center items-center bg-blue-600 hover:bg-white   hover:text-blue-600">
                            <button
                                className=" flex flex-row items-center justify-between gap-3 "
                            >
                                <p className='text-[13px] font-semibold text-gray-200'>Create Task</p>
                                <div className='bg-blue-400 rounded-full w-[26px] h-[26px] flex items-center justify-center'>
                                    <HiPlus className=" w-[16px] h-[16px] text-gray-200   " />
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='grid grid-flow-col grid-cols-4 w-full mt-1 justify-items-center  h-auto gap-x-4  pl-5 pr-5  '>
                    {/* backlock */}
                    <div className='flex flex-col  align-middle w-[100%] items-center'>
                        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center align-middle w-[90%] h-[100px] items-center'>

                            <button className=" shadow-gray-300 h-[42px] shadow-md text-black border-0 text-base w-full font-semibold pr-3 pl-3 rounded-xl items-center flex justify-between bg-white hover:bg-blue-200  hover:text-blue-600"
                                onClick={() =>
                                    document.getElementById('my_modal_1').showModal()}
                            >
                                <p className='pl-1' id='Backlog' >Backlog</p>
                                <div className=' bg-blue-200 rounded-full w-[25px] h-[25px] flex items-center justify-center'>
                                    <FaPlus className="  text-blue-400   " />
                                </div>
                            </button>



                            <dialog id="my_modal_1" className=" p-10 rounded-3xl bg-white ">
                                <div className=" flex flex-col gap-2">
                                    <div className="flex w-full flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap gap-4">
                                        <select className="select w-full max-w-xs  bg-blue-400 outline-none text-white rounded-2xl font-semibold "
                                            onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}>
                                            <option disabled selected>Post type?</option>
                                            <option id='backlog'>Backlog</option>
                                            <option id='todo'>To Do</option>
                                            <option id='inprogress'>In Progress</option>
                                            <option id='completed'>Completed</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="App">
                                        <header className="App-header">
                                            <div className="todo-input flex flex-col gap-5 pt-3 w-[70%]">
                                                <div className="flex w-full flex-wrap md:flex-nowrap gap-4">
                                                    <select className="select w-full max-w-xs border-none border-inherit bg-blue-400 outline-none text-white rounded-2xl font-semibold"
                                                        onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)}>
                                                        <option disabled selected>Pick your Title.</option>
                                                        <option id='banner' className='bg-red-400'>Banner</option>
                                                        <option id='illustration'>Illustration</option>
                                                        <option id='video'>Video</option>
                                                        <option id='uiux'>UI UX</option>

                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <input
                                                    className='w-60% h-[20px] bg-white outline-none border-b-2 text-black'
                                                    id='Title'
                                                    type="text"
                                                    placeholder="Description"
                                                    value={desc}
                                                    onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
                                                />
                                                <p className="py-4 text-gray-400">Press ESC key or click the button below to close</p>
                                                <form method="dialog" className='flex flex-row  gap-2'>
                                                    <button className="btn bg-blue-500 text-white border-0 outline-none hover:bg-white hover:text-black" onClick={handleAddTodo}>Add</button>
                                                    <button className="btn bg-blue-500 text-white border-0 outline-none hover:bg-white hover:text-black">Close</button>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>
                                        </header>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </dialog>
                        </div>



                        <div className='flex flex-col justify-center w-full items-start '>
                            <ul className="todo-list items-center flex flex-col gap-5 w-full h-auto justify-center ">
                                {(myapp || [])?.map((blog: any, index: number) => {
                                    if (blog.type === "Backlog") {
                                        return <>
                                            <div className='bg-white rounded-2xl flex shadow-lg shadow-gray-300 flex-col w-[90%] justify-center gap-4 items-center'>
                                                <div className='flex flex-row mt-2 justify-between w-[90%] '>
                                                    <h1 className='text-black w-[90%] '>
                                                        <li className=' text-gray-700 md:break-words w-[90%] mb-3 flex flex-row text-xs justify-between items-center rounded-lg' id={blog.title} key={index}>
                                                            {blog.title}
                                                            {/* {JSON.stringify(_cards)} */}
                                                        </li>
                                                    </h1>
                                                    <button className="  text-gray-300  items-center flex justify-center   w-[10%] h-[20px] " onClick={() => handleRemoveTodo(index)}>
                                                        <BsThreeDots />
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <li className=' text-gray-700 md:break-words w-[90%] mb-3 flex flex-row text-xs justify-between items-center rounded-lg' id={blog.desc} key={`blog-${index}`}>
                                                    {blog.desc}
                                                </li>
                                            </div>

                                        </>;
                                    }

                                }

                                )}

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

its my context file in contexts folder
'use client'

import { createContext, useEffect, useState,Provider } from "react";
import React from 'react'
import Middle from "../component/Middle";

const Contexts =createContext()

function LocalSContext() {
    const [task, setTask] = useState('');
    const [tyPe, setType] = useState('');
    const [desc, setDesc] = useState('');

    const blog = {
        "type": tyPe,
        "title": task,
        "desc": desc
    }
    //localstorage aas todonuudig awah

    const [myapp, setMypp] = useState(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myApp')) || [];
        }
    })
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('myApp', JSON.stringify(myapp))
    }, [myapp])

    // todo nemegdeh
    const handleAddTodo = () => {

        if (myapp !== null) {
            setMypp([...myapp, blog]);
            setDesc('')
        }
    };

    const handleRemoveTodo = (index: number) => {
        const newTodos = myapp.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
        setMypp(newTodos);
    };

  return (
    <Contexts.Provider value={{setTask, desc, myapp, setDesc, setType, handleAddTodo, handleRemoveTodo}}>
            <Middle/>
    </Contexts.Provider>
  )
}


export {Contexts,LocalSContext}

const { setTask, desc, myapp, setDesc, setType, handleAddTodo, handleRemoveTodo } = useContext(Contexts)
giving error on values -
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setTask' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.useContext)(...)' as it is undefined.
at Middle (./app/component/Middle.tsx:33:13)
digest: "44794283"
23 |
24 |

25 |  const { setTask, desc, myapp, setDesc, setType, handleAddTodo, handleRemoveTodo } = useContext(Contexts)
|          ^
26 |
27 |  // Blog Local----
28 |
GET / 500 in 939ms

And in my page --
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured
Can you guys help me. sry English not good and im beginner.

Try passing in a default value to your createContext() call.
It looks like your component is reading the state of your context before the values are populated, which means none of the props on your object exist yet.
Check out the docs for more info: https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext
Try this instead:
// Set empty object as default so destructuring returns `undefined` 
// for missing variables instead of throwing an error

const Contexts = createContext({})

// Or, set actual defaults
const Contexts = createContext({
   setTask: ...
   desc: ...
// etc
})


Thanks man. I found the solution and it is just like yours but I got problems again Im trying to find the solution again :(

interface MidContext{  myapp:{blog:any}[];  blog:{title:string, type:string,desc:string};  setMypp:(myapp:any[])=>void;  setTask:(task:any)=>void;  setDesc:(desc:any)=>void;  setType:(tyPe:any)=>void;  handleAddTodo:any;  handleRemoveTodo:any;  desc:string }.         did I write it wrong? because it giving me error:TypeError: setDesc is not a function. (In 'setDesc(e.target.value)', 'setDesc' is undefined)

I fixed it. The problem was I was putting my Context.Provider in wrong file.
